# Uncaught ReferenceError: Quill is not defined

Tags: quill

I downloaded a project from github. It had alot of bugs however I fixed almost all of them and now the app is running fine on my AWS server.

You can view the entire project at https://github.com/Moswag/job-hub

When I try to access the app through browser, the browser just keeps on loading and when I check console, it logs

Uncaught ReferenceError: Quill is not defined
at (index):378

Which leads to me to :

```
   var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
        theme: 'snow'
   });
```

I can see in the logs, no errors are showing up
[image]

I am more of a server side guy and I am not sure what exactly is the frontend issue here.

Attaching screenshots for better understanding.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Comment: How is the quill editor loaded?

Comment: how do I find this out?